# Firestore add new map keys

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a map in Firestore that I filled with new messages such as keys and Timestamp as values, something like:

```
history: {
  "user accepted this item": new Date(),
  "user used this item": new Date()
}
```

And here is my code, I want to update the map with a new value but it seems that I cannot use `${}` directly there since it throws syntax error, but if I create an intermediary variable like I did with `historyAction`, Text Editor tells that variable is declared but not used, and as I understand correctly the behavior of updating Firestore data, this will update `historyAction` field that does not exist insted of the value it has. What should I do here?

```
let historyAction = `${user.displayName} accepted this item`;

        firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection("orders")
          .doc(orderId)
          .set({
              history: {
                historyAction: new Date().toISOString()
              }
            }, { merge: true }
          );
```

Answer (score 2):

You should call out the full path of the individual string to update using dot notation, as illustrated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects).

```
        firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection("orders")
          .doc(orderId)
          .set({
            [`history.${historyAction}`]: new Date().toISOString()
          }, { merge: true }
          );
```